# Component Parameter does not change after dropdown change

Tags: angular

I have below code for dropdown based on dropdown.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="input-country">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country"> {{ country }}</option>
</select>

<select *ngIf="country" [(ngModel)]="input-city"  (ngModelChange)="updateCity($event)>
  <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city"> {{ city }} </option>
</select>
```

and then I am loading a div based on selected option and passing country & city parameter to component like this

```
<div *ngIf="city">
    <app-render [country]="country" [city]="city"></app-render>
</div>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
    export class AppComponent {
      private map = new Map<string, string[]>([
        ['Poland', ['Warszawa', 'Krakow']],
        ['USA', ['New York', 'Austin']],
      ])

      country: string;
      city: string;

      get countries(): string[] {
        return Array.from(this.map.keys());
      }

      get cities(): string[] | undefined {
        return this.map.get(this.country);
      }

      updateCity(city){
        this.city = city;
      }

    }
```

I am **getting country & city parameter only the first time selection**. if i select **other option** from dropdown, it **does not update country & city**.

tried to see on *app.component.html* like this, its updating here.

```
<p>Selected country: {{ country }}</p><br>
<p>Selected city: {{ city }}</p>
```

**For Example** -

**First time** if i select 'USA' from country & 'New York' from city. its passing parameter correctly.

**Second time** if i change city to 'Austin', **its not passing 'Austin' to component (city value is not updating/changing)**.

**Please Help/Guide.**

Comment: Can you wshare it in stackbiltz

Comment: try (change) event on <select> instead of  (ngModelChange)

Comment: @AdritaSharma(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gt5sl7)

Comment: @TheNsn666tried (change) event, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion everything is working as it should in your stack blitz.
If you want so see the changes in the console you should put the log to the `ngOnChanges()`

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-render',
  templateUrl: './render.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./render.component.css']
})
export class RenderComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input()
  public country: String;

  @Input()
  public city: String;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log("country : ", this.country);
    console.log("city : ", this.city);
  }

}
```

That way the console logs everytime your city our your country `@Input` gets updated.

Comment: **SOLVED**. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample is working fine.
Just add the following code in `render.component.html` to see bindings working correctly

> {{ country }} -- {{ city }}

For your information, `ngOnInit` is running only the first time the component is initialized (when a city is selected for the first time in your case).
It does not fire every time bindings change.
To log every binding changes you should add `console.log` in `ngOnChanges()` lifehook

Updated sample on StackBlitz to illustrate : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbzahn

Comment: perfect ! **nicely explained.**

Comment: **SOLVED**. Thank you so much.